# How do I reenable control+alt+backspace to kill X in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, x11, xorg

They disabled it, and all recipes I've googled involving adding something to /etc/X11/xorg.conf don't work for me.

What's the proper way to reenable it??

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/174856/31440

Answer (score 1):

See [here](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/enable-ctrl-alt-backspace-in-ubuntukubuntu-10-04lucid-lynx.html).

Enabling Ctrl-Alt-Backspace for Ubuntu 10.04

- Select "System"->"Preferences"->"Keyboard"
- Select the "Layouts" tab and click on the "Layout Options" button.
- Select "Key sequence to kill the X server" and enable "Control + Alt + Backspace".

Answer (score 1):

In an already running X server, per session:

```
setxkbmap $LAYOUT option "terminate:ctrl-alt-bksp"
```

Globally as a X configuration in **xorg.conf**

```
Section "InputClass"
    Identifier "keyboard defaults"
    MatchIsKeyboard "on"

    Option "XKbOptions" "terminate:ctrl-alt-bksp"
EndSection
```

Comment: I've already tried this one, it doesn't work.

Comment: Those options are not permanent. The session's configuration system is at liberty to disable them again.

Comment: one is forgetting that the environment variable $LAYOUT is not available by default on all machines

Comment: @DwightSpencer: In this case `$LAYOUT` is not meant to be a environment varialble, but the name of the layout of the users choice.

Comment: @datenwolf that makes sense, would there be a way to list available layouts?

Comment: @DwightSpencer: xkb is a very powerfull infrastructure and a list of all possible combinations of layouts, variants and so on could become very long. A good starting point is the files in `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols` and to descent the option tree from there. See the manpage of `setxkbmap` on how to query information. I'm not entirely sure how the keyboad configuration tools of the big DEs go about that problem; I'd have to read their sources for that.

Comment: @DwightSpencer: Also `man xkeyboard-config` for a curated list of configurations.